# HTML 5 video within iPhone image frame

Tags: iphone, html, video

I'm somewhat hesitant to ask this question because it it is only borderline software development, but I've had zero luck finding what I need anywhere else.

I am building a landing page for an iPhone app and would like to have a video of the app in use that plays inside an image frame of an actual iPhone device (Apple does this on many of their marketing pages). I don't care about the video being played on anything pre-HTML 5, it can be as simple as an mp4.

Are there any tools out there that will easily generate this sort of functionality for me? Given how often I see this sort of thing, I'm surprised that I am having so much trouble finding something that just =gives it to me out of the box.

Alternatively, I am not opposed to coding something myself, so if that's the only option, a suitable answer to this question would be a pointer to some info on the best way to generically overlay an HTML 5 video on top of an image (the iPhone frame).

Comment: The same way you'd overlay anything over anything else in HTML, using CSS. There are countless ways of laying out web pages, but the fact you're dealing specifically with a picture of an iPhone and a video of your website do not change the fundamental nature of the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you probably don't find anything is probably because it's so simple. Put a `<video>` tag inside a `<div>` tag, set background-image of the frame, add some padding so the video is centered within the frame, and voila.