# Play HTML5 Video Inside an iPhone Image Frame

Tags: html, css, html5-video

Someone asked a similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15094340/1822824) and they received a basic answer with no code. I followed their advice and created my own code.

I am trying to play a HTML5 video inside an iPhone image frame. Like so:

[image]

My image is 300 pixels by 629 pixels. The problem is I get a vertical scroll bar in Safari 6 (the browser I'm targeting) even though the window is large enough to view. The scroll bar also appears on my code Fiddle.

**Why am I getting this vertical scroll bar?**

My code is as follows:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/rZYTn/

**HTML**

```
<div class="myVideo">
<video width="253" height="447" controls autoplay>
  <source src="videos/keyboard.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.myVideo {
    background-image: url(iphone.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 300px;
    height: 629px;
    padding-top: 93px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Extra space and scroll bar on Fiddle:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extra space is due to video size and div size (width & height)

**fix**

```
.myVideo {
    background-image: url(iphone.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 254px;
    height: 455px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This might also remove scroll bar.

Comment: actually setting top padding 10px removed the scrollbar